# Not an answer declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/317065/621316

It is 100% a "link-only answer", which unless I'm mistaken are to be deleted according to the rules. What should I do when coming across such an "answer"? I would think that is what flagging as not an answer is specifically for, since this is not an issue of how well the answer answered the question, but rather that according to the rules this is not something that qualifies as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, thats really bad. It is highly voted/accepted though :(

Comment: Interestingly enough, bluefeet warned the poster a year ago that it could be deleted, with no positive action taken by the poster.

Comment: Shog9 deleted it 18 minutes ago...

Comment: And this is either [status-complete] or duplicated of the question where Shog answers that this kind of answers should be deleted.