# What is the objective policy for "Not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags, vote-to-delete

Sometimes it's demotivating when a flag gets rejected, when it's supposed to be helpful. Few examples where my flags are rejected (sometimes mutiple times):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243612/514235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/154820/514235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41667716/514235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032449/514235 (2nd answer by same user)

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284972/514235), link only answers should be deleted. I feel that the Mod might have retained them because they are 'attempting to answer'.

**Question**: Do we have an objective policy for main SO, for when to flag something for "Not an answer"?

---

BTW, I have referred following posts, but still not clear:

- [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/163449)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/163449)

Comment: The first two posts are not just link-only. They do answer the question, albeit in a very short form. Feel free to downvote them if you feel they are not helpful. The 3rd is clearly an attempt at answering; you can disagree with the merit of the answer, so again, you can downvote it. The last link, again, is clearly an attempt at answering. There may be other reasons to delete it, for which you can use a custom flag, but again, NAA does not apply.

Comment: Only the first two might be warrant some confusion. Their whole content is also a link. The litmus test is looking at the post [as if the link is not there, is it still an answer on its own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)? In both cases, that is certainly the case. The other two fall very, *very* wide of the mark you already found in the Meta FAQ you link, I'm not sure how to further clarify this for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, If you refer the [linked meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284972/not-an-answer-declined), it suggests that "link only answers" are supposed to be deleted. However, the answer to dupe says that link only answers are still valid. What to derive from it? BTW, regarding the last one, it should be surely deleted. In past my similar flag was accepted where user X had answered something, user Y posted some part of X's answer. That was deleted. In the case of last one, "X = Y". i.e. a same user has copied his accepted answer to another answer. How can it be valid?

Comment: See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: For the last one, I was only addressing the merits of a NAA flag, and why it was correctly declined. I did see there is a custom flag on it now, I did not address that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think *all* of these are answers and not worthy of deletion. I can see why you might have been concerned about the first two, since they consist primarily of a link, but as Martijn said, the link text itself contains the answer to the question. They are short, but accurate and still useful. As for the last two, I don't understand what you think is wrong with those answers, or why they would be worthy of flagging. Lightness Races in Orbit's answer is…not what I would have posted and not especially helpful, but still an answer nevertheless and shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray, Light's answer is actually not discussing the Qn, but giving some advice. The 4th  is 2nd answer from the same user. He has posted an answer, which is accepted by the OP. A very small subset of it, is reflecting in the 2nd answer. Moreover, if you read the comment below it, at least 3 people agree that it's an NAA. In past, I have seen that if an answer is a subset of another answer, then it's deleted. In this case it's both (subset & NAA). Actually the policy is not clear enough. I want to flag this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6243656/514235. But not sure if I should do it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, BTW, suppose if a post is deleteable by a custom flag (e.g the 4th one). However, I flag it as a "Not an answer". Will the post be deleted by Mods by their self-evaluation or will the answer retained, because the flagging was wrong. This will help me to put better flags. Sometimes I flag NAA instead of custom flag, thinking that the Mod will understand that the answer should be deleted. For example, the answer linked in my above comment is not discussing the Qn at all (at least according to me). Should I flag it under custom flag?

Comment: @iammilind: please don't use NAA flags on posts that do not fit that category. NAA flags are initially handled by the community, and moderators on the whole will decline such flags on such posts. NAA flags are viewed together on one page without the question visible, so you run a high risk of the flag being declined purely because we'd evaluate on NAA conditions *only*.

Comment: @iammilind: the point is that post still doesn't meet the NAA bar. It may warrant deletion for the reasons you stated, but NAA is not the only reason a post is deleted. Just because it warrants deletion doesn't make it so the NAA flag applies.

Comment: Lightness isn't giving "advice", he's saying the question cannot be answered because it doesn't make sense. I am very unclear on why you think answers such as these, or [this one you pointed to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243605/are-destructors-overloadable/6243656#6243656), need to be deleted. None of these answers are obvious garbage, they aren't simply rephrasings of other answers, they are clearly applicable to the question, and they actually contain an answer. What do you mean that latedeveloper's answer isn't discussing the question? It quite obviously is.

Comment: Maybe it's an English-as-a-second-language problem? latedeveloper is quoting the sentence from the documentation being asked about, he's saying that, although it says "constructor and destructor", it *means* to say just "constructor", and that this is simply another instance of low-quality documentation from Boost. It is very clear to me (although it might not be correct, but the other answers confirm that it is), but maybe it is phrased in a confusing and indirect way?

Comment: @CodyGray, Somehow I feel that Lightness's answer is not discussing the Qn & going to some different direction. If that would have been answered by some low rep user, then it would have got deleted. I have flagged for undeletion of certain such answers. The "latedeveloper"'s answer is not addressing the Qn, which asks about if the destructors can be overloaded. In some of the SE sites, I have seen that such answers are converted to comment. May be this could be an issue as English is not my native language. From above discussion, I got that it's better to put "custom flag" instead of NAA.